# Populate HighChart with SQLData PHP

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Hi im having a hard time trying to populate my Highchart with my SQL data but there are conditions. say for example how many registered in the month of january and so on--up to december.

Here is my code

```
<?php 
require_once './library/config.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from tbl_users where MonthCreated =   'January' and YearCreated = '2016';");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$jan = $row['count'];
?>
```

Here is my HighChart.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Barangay Statistics</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Requests Report',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Barangay Harapin ang Bukas',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '' //suffix *C
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Complaints',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9,20]
    }, {
        name: 'Services',
        data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
```

Below is where exactly i wanted the value to be shown. But still it shows no value :(

```
        name: 'Registered Constituents',
        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,<?php echo $jan; ?>]
    }]
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried to see what is happening? what does `$jan` contain? I suppose it would be an array? do you mind posting what is in `data` of the series `Registered Constituents`? also, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. 

In the line graph `data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,]`  it shows but when i try replacing 1 with `<?php echo $jan; ?>` it does not show any value/line/dot. The January in my DB has two records.

Comment: sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear. in chrome developer tools, check what is in the `data` variable of `Registered Constituents` series. That way we could see exactly what the expression `<?php echo $jan; ?>` returns and the data looks like.